# Re-using model with different required properties

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have a path that uses complex models with almost identical properties for each http method. The problem is that I want to define *some* required properties for the request of PUT and POST, while no properties are required in GET response (as the server always returns all properties and its mentioned elsewhere in the documentation).

I created a simple cat API to demonstrate what I've tried. The idea is that for GET response the response model doesn't have anything marked as required, but the request of PUT must have a name for the cat.

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: "Cat API"
  version: 1.0.0

paths:
  /cats/{id}:
    parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        type: integer
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return a cat
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GetCat"
    put:
      parameters:
        - name: cat
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/PutCat"
      responses:
        204:
          description: Cat edited
            
definitions:
  Cat:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
  GetCat:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/Cat"
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
  PutCat:
    type: object
    required:
      - name
    properties:
      $ref: "#/definitions/Cat/properties"
```

Swagger Editor says that this is a valid specification, but `name` is set as required for both GET and PUT. The same goes with Swagger UI.

I also tried the following version of `PutCat`:

```yaml
PutCat:
  type: object
  required:
    - name
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/definitions/Cat"
```

But now everything is optional.

I can't figure this out. Is there a way to do this properly?

**EDIT:**

As [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843802/1917648) correctly mentioned, I can use `readOnly` to solve this particular case with GET and PUT.

But let's say I add `breed` property which must be provided (in addition to the `name` property) for PUT. Then I add PATCH method, which can be used to update either `breed` or `name` while the other remains unchanged, and I want to set neither of those as required.

Answer (score 36):

In your example, you can use a single model for both GET and POST/PUT, with properties only used in the GET response marked as `readOnly`. From the [spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-13):

> `readOnly`
>
> Declares the property as "read only". This means that it MAY be sent as part of a response but MUST NOT be sent as part of the request. Properties marked as readOnly being true SHOULD NOT be in the required list of the defined schema. Default value is false.

The spec would look like:

```yaml
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return a cat
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Cat"
    put:
      parameters:
        - name: cat
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Cat"
      responses:
        204:
          description: Cat edited

definitions:
  Cat:
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        readOnly: true
      name:
        type: string
      breed:
        type: string
    required:
      - name
      - breed
```

This means you must PUT the `name` and `breed`:

```js
{
  "name": "Puss in Boots",
  "breed": "whatever"
}
```

and `GET /cats/{id}` must return the `name` and `breed` and may also return the `id`:

```js
{
  "name": "Puss in Boots",
  "breed": "whatever",
  "id": 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue in the example. However, I was a bit careless with my example and updated the question with the scenario of adding a PATCH method for partial updates that doesn't required anything.

Comment: Thank you, but now it looks like both name and breed are required for PATCH as well (there's asterisk after both in Swagger Editor). This is the same problem as in the original question.

I believe there is no solution for this as of now.

Comment: @Helen But the allOf keyword will also appear in the formatted structure and it is ugly. Is there any way to prevent it from appearing in the structure?

Comment: The syntax with `$ref` underneath `properties` doesn't appear to work with Open API 3.0.

Comment: @ChrisHaines: Yeah that example is not valid... I'll remove it. Unfortunately, there's no elegant way to handle GET/POST/PATCH differences. :(

Answer (score 11):

I've had a similar problem. Turned out that my indentation was wrong.
The following syntax should work:

```
PutCat:
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/definitions/Cat"
    - type: object
      required: [name]
```

Comment: This is the best solution to hide some fields from `put` which are only required for `post`. By adding a `properties:` there on the level of "type", and just the property name with a `readOnly: true`.