# Reference parent object properties in "required" section of child object in Swagger

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, swagger, swagger-2.0

In Swagger, is it possible to reference a parent object's properties when defining what properties of a child object are `required`?

For example, given the following base class:

```
definitions:
  Pet:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      owner:
        type: string
```

I would like to have two child classes: one for creating a Pet (where all properties are required in the payload) and another for updating a Pet (where none are required). I tried achieving this by doing:

```
  CreatePetRequest:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
    required:
      - name
      - owner

  UpdatePetRequest:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
```

However, this doesn't work. Instead, an exception is raised:

```
swagger_spec_validator.common.SwaggerValidationError: Required list has properties not defined: ['name', 'owner']
```

How can I achieve this? Is it even possible with Swagger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-using model with different required properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839706/re-using-model-with-different-required-properties)

Answer (score 0):

I see the exact same issue with a particular version of `swagger-spec-validator` pip package, in my case it was the version `2.0.4` which fixed the issue. Install it using `pip install swagger-spec-validator==2.0.4` or pin the package with version number in `requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was indeed on 2.0.3 when I tried this. I'll give it a go with 2.1.0 (the newest) later on and hopefully have more luck.