# Reusing references to models but redefining required properties

Tags: swagger, openapi

> There's a year old question with a similar title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839706/re-using-model-with-different-required-properties), but the
>   only answer does not answer the question fully so hoping that things
>   have changed since I'm trying again.

I've a model of a `Car` which I would like to use with `GET` requests for creating new instances in which I require to have `name`.

Additionally, I would like to use this with `PUT` requests to update an existing instance. Update requests should not have all properties, the `Car` identifier is already specified in the path and only the present properties would be 'merged' into the existing object.

I tried using the following spec:

```
CarProperties:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
      title: Car Name
      description: A friendly name for this car.
      minLength: 1
      md:
        type: object
        hidden: 'true'
    description:
      type: string
      title: Car Description
      description: A detailed description of the car.
      md:
        type: object
        hidden: 'true'

UpdateCar:
  allOf:
    -  { $ref: '#/definitions/CarProperties' }
  type: object  

NewCar:
  allOf:
    -  { $ref: '#/definitions/CarProperties' }
  type: object  
  required: [name]
```

I expected having `name` a required property only in `NewCar`, however in both `NewCar` and `UpdateCar` the property `name` is optional.

How can I specify a subset of required properties from a referenced model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling for a while it seems like I had bad indentation for the `required` field. The following syntax seems to produce what I wanted:

```
CarProperties:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
      title: Car Name
      description: A friendly name for this car.
      minLength: 1
      md:
        type: object
        hidden: 'true'
    description:
      type: string
      title: Car Description
      description: A detailed description of the car.
      md:
        type: object
        hidden: 'true'

UpdateCar:
  allOf:
    - { $ref: '#/definitions/CarProperties' }
    - type: object  

NewCar:
  allOf:
    - { $ref: '#/definitions/CarProperties' }
    - type: object
      required: [name]
```

Now I have:

1. `NewCar` entity with a required `name` field.
2. `UpdateCar` entity with an optional `name` field.
3. If I want to add another property to `Car` I only need to do it in one place.