# OpenAPI: Design a reusable schema definition for GET, PUT, POST

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi, nullable, dto

I am using OpenAPI 3.0 to design and implement a simple API to allow basic CRUD operations on database entities.

Let's assume an entity `Pet` with some client-given properties (`name` & `age`) and some generated properties (`id` & `created`):

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        created:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        name:
          type: string
        age:
          type: integer
```

I want to specify REST endpoints to POST, GET, PUT (and if possible PATCH) a pet:

```yaml
paths:

  /pets:
    post:
      operationId: createPet
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: boolean
 
  /pets/{id}:
    parameters:
      - name: id
        schema:
          type: string
        in: path
        required: true

    get:
      operationId: getPet
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"

    put:
      operationId: updatePet
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: boolean

    patch:
      operationId: alterPet
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: boolean
```

From a logical point of view, the following properties are **required** per endpoint:

- GET: `id`, `created`, `name`, `age`
- POST: `name`, `age`
- PUT: `name`, `age`
- PATCH: `name` or `age` (or none depending on implementation)

I see two major approaches here:

**Approach 1: Leave all properties optional**

The `Pet` DTO is used as a shell where *all* properties are optional as defined above. It is left to the server & client to check if the required properties are filled on an endpoint call. If non-required properties are set in a POST/PUT/PATCH request body, they will be ignored.

*pros:*

- Single, simple, and symmetric DTO schema definition in the API specification.
- Smooth integration of the "GET -> modify -> PUT" workflow on the client side (e.g., a React frontend with Formik).
- Supports the PATCH endpoint out-of-the-box.

*cons:*

- All properties are optional and it is very tedious to handle these `string | undefined` types in Typescript. This is especially annoying in the GET direction as we know that all properties will be filled as long as we retrieve the `Pet` DTO.
- The implementational "pain" is spread over the server and all possible clients.

**Approach 2: Define separate DTO schemas for all operations**

We introduce a `GetPet`, `PutPet`, `PostPet`, and `PatchPet` with corresponging `required` lists in the API specification. Yes, `PutPet` and `PostPet` can be identical, but maybe we want to allow a modified `GetPet` to be used as `PutPet` to streamline the "GET -> modify -> PUT" workflow for the client.

Imagine the `Pet` entity having 5+ generated properties and 20+ client-given properties. We do not want to flat define 4 variations of each entity, but use some kind of inheritance instead. Is there a way to introduce a `BasePet` bearing all properties (set to optional) and let the 4 operation-specific DTOs extend it with just overriding the `required` list?

*pros:*

- Easier implementation for client & server as optionality is clarified for all properties.
- The "pain" is handled in the API specification.

*cons:*

- The API specification grows in complexity. It is not clear to me if the desired inhertance is possible and how it is specified.
- Scalability & maintainability of the API may suffer.

So my question on this topic: How can the inhertiance of the DTOs be specified for OpenAPI 3.0? Are there better alternatives? I am happy for all suggestions concerning these thoughts on an API for basic CRUD operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-using model with different required properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839706/re-using-model-with-different-required-properties)

Comment: @slifty probably not, as the schema is the same for read and write, and this is different from the requirement of OP.

Answer (score 1):

I did face a similar issue while designing an API for a client recently. The trick here is to `$ref:` redundancies in the schemata for the different routes. For simplicity, I will only define `GET`, `POST` and `PATCH`.

**Note:** In this case it is easier, as the schema for *write* operations is a subset of the schema for the *read* operation.

By contrast, imagine a *user*-object,  where there is a `password` field, it should be writable, but not readable. In this case, you would need three different schemata:

- `userRead`
- `userWrite`
- `userCommonFieldsForReadAndWrite`

In any case, here is one possible solution to your question:

```yaml
paths:
  /pets:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/petCreateUpdate"
      responses:
        "201":
          description: Pet created.
          headers:
            Location:
              schema:
                type: string
              description: points to the Pet resource created. Can be directly used in a subsequent GET request.
              example: "Location: /pets/32"
  /pets/{id}:
    parameters:
      - name: id
        schema:
          type: string
        in: path
        required: true
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Pet with given id returned.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/petRead"
        "404":
          description: Pet with given id not found.
    patch:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/petCreateUpdate"
      responses:
        "204":
          description: Pet updated successfully.

components:
  schemas:

    petRead:
      allOf:
        - type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: integer
              format: int32
              minimum: 1
            created:
              type: string
              format: date-time
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/petCreateUpdate"

    petCreateUpdate:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        age:
          type: number
          format: integer
          minimum: 1
          maximum: 100
```

This renders in SwaggerEditor as follows:

- [POST for the Pet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1kNV.png)
- [GET for the Pet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXRGR.png)
- [PATCH for the Pet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSjXy.png)