# Remove Model properties in WebAPI POST but keep for GET in Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-web-api2

I have a few properties that capture timestamps when data is inserted or updated in the database. I don't want these properties visible in Swagger in POST requests, how can I show these in GET requests but not in the POST endpoints?

```
public class BaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets Date Created
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "object_created", IsRequired = false)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets Date Updated
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "object_updated", IsRequired = false)]
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You might need to make these properties read-only. In OpenAPI 2.0/3.0, [`readOnly`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843802/113116) means this property appears in _responses_ (e.g. GET responses) but not included in _requests_ (e.g. POST/PUT).

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the setter private, e.g.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; private set; }
}
```

Then those properties will be hidden from POST and PUT operations.

Answer (score 0):

See in topic "hide property from displaying":
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/1230

Another way: you can create two model for that. I thing that way is the best.

Comment: Hiding the property would unfortunately mean that itd be hidden on the POST and the GET, which I don't want.

Comment: Creating two models seems too complicated, but perhaps this is the only way?