# openapi distinct get and post items

Tags: python-3.x, swagger-ui, openapi

I have openapi requirements

```
   components:
     schemas:
       UserGet:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/myElements'
       UserPost:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/myElements'

       myElements:
         type: array
         items:
           allOf:
             - $ref: 'myEnumItems'

       myEnumItems:
          type: String
          enum:
             - 'state1'
             - 'state2'
```

`UserGet` and `UserPost` using `myElements` schema.

Problem is `myElements` have `myEnumItems` with `enum` `state1` and `state2`, which I want to restrict new user can POST only any of two values `['state1','state2']`, but in GET request there may be already available data in db for existing users for example `'state3'`. Since `'state3'` is not in `enum`, for GET this use case will fail.

I am looking for idea to overcome this issue.

I am using https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/ as reference.

It looks similar to [Re-using model with different required properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839706/re-using-model-with-different-required-properties) but readOnly is not working for me. I am not sure which part I am missing.